# How do I get a running sum in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to get a running sum in sqlite. Right now I have:

```
SELECT 
    type, 
    count, 
    SUM(count) as startIndex 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            things.type, 
            COUNT(things.name) as count 
        FROM 
            things 
            INNER JOIN thingGroups 
            ON thingID = things.id 
            INNER JOIN groups 
            ON groups.id=thingGroups.groupID 
        WHERE 
            groups.name='Space' 
        GROUP BY things.type 
        ORDER BY type
    ) 
GROUP BY type, count
```

This gives me:

```
Name A, 2, 2
Name B, 3, 3
Name C, 3, 3
```

I'm looking for:

```
Name A, 2, 0
Name B, 3, 2
Name C, 3, 5
```

Comment: can you show us a sample of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select TYPE, COUNT,
       (select count(*)
        from things t2 INNER JOIN
             thingGroups 
             ON thingID = t2.id INNER JOIN
             groups 
             ON groups.id=thingGroups.groupID 
        WHERE groups.name='Space' and
              t2.type < things.type
       ) as cumsum
from (SELECT things.type, COUNT(things.name) as count 
      FROM things INNER JOIN
           thingGroups 
           ON thingID = things.id INNER JOIN
           groups 
           ON groups.id=thingGroups.groupID 
       WHERE groups.name='Space' 
       GROUP BY things.type
      ) t
order by type
```

By the way, the order by should always go in the outermost query (unless you are using some sort of limit or top to get a subset of rows).

Comment: This is nearly correct, the cumsum column have the values 2, 5, 8. I'm looking to get the values 0, 2, 5. If like cumsum is one value ahead.

Comment: I figured it out, the <= needs to be a <